# Angle Turned Into Radians And Then Into dx. Not Working As I Thought

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a very simple game, just to learn Java more. I do have some experience with it, but not much.
The game is supposed to be Chicken Invaders-like.

So here's my problem.
I created a Bullet class, and the player will fire bullets when clicking space.
In the constructor, I require an angle as an int parameter. Then I turn it into Radians and use Math.cos and Math.sin to turn it into the directions the bullet should move in each axis:

```
public Bullet(int x, int y, int angle) {
    super(x, y);

    double rad = Math.toRadians(angle);

    this.dx = Math.cos(rad) * speed;
    this.dy = Math.sin(rad) * speed;
}
```

The speed is a static final value.

When I update the bullet, I simply add dx and dy to the x and y variables.

When the player shoots, I create 3 bullets with the angles of 270, 265 and 275, all starting in the same place:

```
GamePanel.bullets.add(new Bullet(x + (width - Bullet.width) / 2, y + 5, 270));
GamePanel.bullets.add(new Bullet(x + (width - Bullet.width) / 2, y + 5, 265));
GamePanel.bullets.add(new Bullet(x + (width - Bullet.width) / 2, y + 5, 275));
```

What I expected was 3 bullets, one going straight up and the other two a bit to the right or the left, with the same rate, but instead the left one is a bit more off than the right one:

[image: An image of the game]

I'm not sure why the left one is not the same as  the right one. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but I can't track it down.

Comment: what are the types of `dx` and `dy`?

Comment: @Bathsheba:  They'd be double as a result of `Math#sin` and `Math#cos`.

Comment: Not necessarily. I want to know for sure. The trig looks correct at a first glance.

Comment: What was your intent behind `x + (width - Bullet.width) / 2`?  Did you want to add x after the quotient, or add everything together before dividing by 2?

Comment: Are your `x` and `y` integers?

Comment: dx and dy are doubles.

Comment: I mean the `x` and `y` you add those `dx` and `dy` to.

Comment: x + (width - Bullet.width) / 2 - I start drawing boxes from the top left. So I want the box to start at the middle of the player (x + width / 2) minus half the bullet's width (so the entire bullet would be centered).

Comment: The x and y were ints. I changed them to doubles and it fixed it all! Thank you, I get the problem now.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was x and y being ints. Forgot about that :)
Basically, I added dx and dy (that were doubles) to x and y (that were int).
Because of the way Java turns doubles into ints, the negative ones got rounded differently, which caused the x to go more to the left.

Changing the x and y to doubles themselves (And then casting them to ints when drawing) solved it.

Thank you RealSkeptic and everyone for helping me :D

Solved!